# How to set method name for custom method in caret?

Tags: r, r-caret

Suppose we have defined a custom model in `caret`, how do we assign the method name?

```
library(caret)
m1=getModelInfo("lda")[[1]]

c0=train(Species~.,iris,method="lda")
c1=train(Species~.,iris,method=m1)
> c0$method
[1] "lda"
> c1$method
[1] "custom"
```

The `"custom"` name becomes a problem when I have more than one custom method, and then I need to, say, plot the results -- having identical labels are not good.

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of downstream analysis you want to do with the train object?

Comment: If you are only plotting in the downstream analysis, you could just set the method slot with `c1$method <- "your.method"`. Do so at your own risk, I am not sure at what point `caret` might use that slot.